# for loop not working in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, loops, for-loop

I've been always using the following format for a "for loop" in a shell script :

example:

```
for i in {11001..110039}  
do
cp /home/usr/BB${i}  /home/usr/
```

now, I am getting the following error :

```
/home/usr/BB{11001..11039} does not exist
```

it should consider all the files BB11001 to BB11039, it was always working like this, and now I don't know why am I getting this error.
Any help ?

Comment: is grammar right? should it be `for i in words; do
 #statements
done`?

Comment: yes the syntax is like what you wrote

Comment: so does /home/usr/BB11001 exist?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash.

Edit #1 (PoC):

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ cat t.sh 
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..5}
do
echo $i
done
$ ./t.sh
1
2
3
4
5
$
```

And with /bin/sh:

```
$ cat t.sh 
#!/bin/sh

for i in {1..5}
do
echo $i
done
$ ./t.sh
{1..5}
$
```

Comment: Can you provide your bash version (if you're really using bash)?

Comment: GNU bash version 4.1.5

Comment: I'm not sure in which version that syntax was introduced, but v4.1.5 seems to be recent enough to implement it.

Comment: I've tried it now with version 4.2.45 and it's running flawlessly. Anyway, you can always use the `for ((i=11001;i<=110039;i++));` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax should be:

for i in {11001..110039};
do
cp /home/usr/BB${i}  /home/usr/;
done

Comment: It's irrelevant. OP syntax is correct as far as he's using a 'done' statement after cp